# Convert the amount to 2 decimals

Tags: nunjucks

I am using `nunjucks` template:

```
<td class="alignright">{{ item.amount / 100 }}</td>
```

Using `10050 / 100`, I am getting `100.5`, I want to have it like `100.50`.

Question:

```
How do I convert the amount to 2 decimals, after divided by 100?
```

Comment: use toFixed() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: @Borna, you mean to fixed to 2 decimal, before passing it to the template?

Comment: no,using jquery ,wait i making a demo for u...hope it will help u

Comment: @Borna, I cannot use jquery, basically I am just use it to convert the template to plain html, by using nunjucks.renderString().

Comment: srry i didn't help u coz i have no idea about  nunjucks.ok,hope u find your desired result..best of luck ..let me know anytime  if u need to this prob using jquery.

Comment: @Borna thanks for tryin to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
env = nunjucks.configure( ... );
...
env.addFilter('fixed', function(num, length) {
    return num.toFixed(length || 2);
});
```

---

```
<td class="alignright">{{ item.amount / 100 | fixed }}</td> <= need parenthesis!
```

---

Worked example

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

env.addFilter('fixed', function(num, length) {
    return  num.toFixed(2 || length);
});

env.addGlobal('fixed', function(num, length) { 
    return  num.toFixed(2 || length);
})

var html = env.renderString(
    'Filter: {{ (totalAmt / 100) | fixed }}, GlobalFunc: {{ fixed(totalAmt / 100) }}', 
    { totalAmt: 500030 });
console.log(html);
```

Comment: I tried your method: 
env = nunjucks.configure();
    env.addFilter('fixed', function(num, length) {
        return num.toFixed(length || 2);
    });

    var html = nunjucks.renderString('{{ totalAmt / 100 | fixed  }}', { totalAmt: 500030 });, but it is giving me 5000.3

Comment: Try `env.renderString(...)` instead `nunjucks.renderString`

Comment: I change that, it still the same.

Comment: Heh, It's my mistake: in `amount / 100 | fixed` filter applied to 100. To get correct result we need parenthesis around value. I fixed example. Also I add global function. You can used it too.